# How many recurrence relations are possible for a sequence?

Tags: recurrence-relations

How many recurrence relations are possible for a sequence?
Example:
$$
5, 11, 29, 83, 245, \ldots
$$
We have two recurrence relation:

1. $T_n = 3T_{n-1} - 4$
2. $T_n = T_{n-1} + 6 \cdot 3^{n-1}$

Both give $T_n = 3^n + 2$

Comment: One can note that $T_n=3^n+2$ does not solve 2.

Comment: Sorry? Plugging $T_{n-1}=3^{n-1}+2$ in the RHS of 2. and checking that the result is not always $3^n+2$, what else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $s$ be an arbitrary number. Then the recurrence
$$T_n=s\left(3T_{n-1}-4\right)+(1-s)\left(  T_{n-1}+6\cdot 3^{n-1}   \right)$$
gives the same sequence for any $s$.

Comment: So which recurrence amongst this is correct? And what if s<=0 ?

Comment: Also how many recurrence relations are possible for a given sequence?

Comment: All are correct, $s$ can be anything. So there are infinitely many. The interesting thing would be to put restrictions on the *type* of recurrence. Or perhaps even though there are infinitely many they are in some sense finitely generated.